# PHP SQL: Way to skip over section of a query if variable is blank

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a query that uses input from a search form where Brand, Type and Price are optional input fields:

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE `brand` LIKE "%' . $brand . '%" AND `type` LIKE "%' . $type. '%" AND `price` LIKE "%' . $price . '%"
```

I am wondering if there is a way to say 'all' if nothing is entered into one of the fields. For example if they do not enter a value in the price field is there a way to tell SQL to just say ignore that section, eg:

```
AND `price` LIKE "*";
```

So the reuslts are still filtered by Brand and Type but can have any Price.

Any advice on this is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ariel mentioned, it would be better to have PHP do the filtering as you build the query. Here's a code sample for doing it that way:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `database`';
$where = array();
if ($brand !== '') $where[] = '`brand` LIKE "%'.$brand.'%"';
if ($type !== '')  $where[] = '`type` LIKE "%'.$type.'%"';
if ($price !== '') $where[] = '`price` LIKE "%'.$price.'%"';
if (count($where) > 0) {
  $sql .= ' WHERE '.implode(' AND ', $where);
} else {
  // Error out; must specify at least one!
}
// Run $sql
```

**NOTE**: Please, please, *please* make sure that the `$brand`, `$type`, and `$price` variable contents are sanitized before you use them this way or you make yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (ideally you should be using the PHP [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) database connector with prepared statements to sanitize the input).

Comment: Change the initialization of $sql to 'SELECT * from `database` where 1=1' then you don't have to worry about all the "AND"s.  Just pile all the extra clauses with "AND" after that.

Comment: "all the AND's"? There's exactly one "AND" in my script. My method reduces the need to one, while yours would have four repetitions.

Comment: If you like building up arrays and then concating them together, rather than writing legible SQL, have at it.

Comment: If you like writing long, rambling, inefficient SQL queries that put more load on the database server than they need, to return a simple result, have at it your way.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you do that in the front end language, not SQL.

But `price LIKE '%'` does, in fact, mean all (except for NULLs). So you are probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your form fields organized, you can do something like:

```
<?php
    $fields = array(
        // Form    // SQL
        'brand' => 'brand',
        'type'  => 'type',
        'price' => 'price',
    );

    $sql  = 'SELECT * FROM `database`';
    $comb = ' WHERE ';
    foreach($fields as $form => $sqlfield)
    {
        if (!isset($_POST[$form]))
            continue;
        if (empty($_POST[$form]))
            continue;
        // You can complicate your $fields structure and e.g. use an array
        // with both sql field name and "acceptable regexp" to check input
        // ...

        // This uses the obsolete form for mysql_*
        $sql .= $comb . $sqlfield . ' LIKE "%'
             . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$form])
             . '"';
        /* To use PDO, you would do something like
             $sql .= $comb . $sqlfield . 'LIKE ?';
             $par[] = $_POST[$form];
        */
        $comb = ' AND ';
    }
    // Other SQL to go here
    $sql .= " ORDER BY brand;";

    /* In PDO, after preparing query, you would bind parameters
       - $par[0] is value for parameter 1 and so on.
       foreach($par as $n => $value)
           bindParam($n+1, '%'.$value.'%');
    */
```